# MySQL finding duplicate records with AND statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates

I have a table called book.
It has three columns : book_id, book_name, book_writer. When I want to find the duplicate books from the table, I can find it with the SQL query below, but there can be books with the same name that have been written by different writers. So I want to make a double check by adding the writer_name to my SQL query, but couldn't make it work. Here is my query.

```
SELECT book_name, COUNT(*) c FROM book GROUP BY book_name HAVING c > 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `book_writer` column to the select list and the group by list:

```
SELECT   book_name, book_writer, COUNT(*) c 
FROM     book 
GROUP BY book_name, book_writer
HAVING   c > 1;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I was messing up with AND & OR statements.
It says I can accept the answer in six minutes, so I couldn't accept it right away.